# Snowflake task for historical data load, time limit

Tags: task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to do a full historical load, including transformations, from one table in Snowflake to another. I expect it it to take over an hour.
I would like to schedule this load and have it run overnight so that I don't have to stay connected to the network or risk a connection issue.

I tried to use a scheduled task to do this.

Problem: There is a 60 minute limit.  You can make it shorter (STATEMENT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 60), but you can’t make it longer it appears. https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tasks-ts.html#task-timed-out-or-exceeded-the-schedule-window

Anyone else experience this and have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to scale up your WAREHOUSE, which makes sense if your TASK is parallelizable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a soft-limit on the execution of tasks per each account. You should be able to contact Snowflake support to get this extended.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should raise a case to the snowflake support and request for the task limit to be increased. Please check the time it usually takes for the task to complete and request that time to be set . The limit will be set at the account level.Also the development is working on a future feature where the timeout can be set at the task level.